# Is there a typed wrapper for ical4j?

Tags: java, icalendar, ical4j

Ical4j seems pretty robust, but the interface is really unintuitive. It gives you untyped iterators that you need to cast to it's internal types, and all the dates are stored in it's own Date implementation, rather than joda. Has anyone written a wrapper (or newer library) that is more pleasant to use?

Answer (score 2):

ical4j will gain support for generics and other Java 5+ features post-release 1.0.

This won't necessarily solve the headaches associated with the Java date/time API but should make it easier for iterating.